# iOS 'convert to pdf' tools produce incomplete conversions

Tags: ipad, pdf, file-conversion

On Mac, the print dialog 'Save to pdf' features captures all types of images and image-like things.

On iPad, the tools I have tried run into problems, e.g.:

1. On https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable, no MathML is included in the conversion or only that which appears on the first page or two.
2. On http://www.businessinsider.com/7-gifs-trigonometry-sine-cosine-2013-5, the animated gifs are properly converted to single static images, but surrounding text is lost.

Do any tools work properly on these webpages?

Answer (score 1):

I posted similarly to [ipadforums](http://www.ipadforums.net/threads/ios-convert-to-pdf-apps-produce-incomplete-conversions.131443), received a suggestion from [twerpoet](http://www.ipadforums.net/members/twerppoet.28530), and pursued that path to identify some solutions that worked for the above web pages.